# Altering routing of user/login

Tags: 7, routes, users

I have a use case where I need to adjust the landing of the route, user/login to direct to a custom developed user/register page once clicked. What's the quickest method of doing this without overloading the core User module with changes?

Comment: hook_init function in your custom module or you cantry rules module for custom redirect of the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) module to redirect without touching any code

> The Login Destination module allows you to customize the destination
>   that a user is redirected to after logging in, registering to the site
>   (7.x), using a one-time login link or logging out (7.x). The
>   destination can be an internal page or an external URL. It is possible
>   to specify certain conditions like referring pages or user roles and
>   make the destination depend upon them. You may use PHP snippets to
>   provide custom conditions and destinations. It is also possible to
>   keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) if you don't want to touch code

event: drupal initializes

condition: url: user/login and user/register

action: redirect to your url

Rules:

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

Comment: Is it possible with Rules to define behavior based on login from specific sources? I have a ctools-based Multi-step registration and it appears that when I use Triggers to route logged in users to the new URL, it was affecting users who registered with multi-step.

Comment: so far as I know, it should pick it up, unless you are overriding the session data, you would be using core login functionality just in your own format - only takes about 6 minutes to find out if it would work...